# How Django evaluates object managers when we have multiple ones?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Consider the following objects in Django ORM:

```
class Post(models.Model):
   ...
   published = PublishedPostManager()
   objects = models.Manager()
```

Now in the Django admin, only the published ones are shown. Could we change the behavior, so the Django ORM uses objects by default without any order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the [**`docs`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#default-managers):

> If you use custom Manager objects, take note that the first Manager Django encounters (in the order in which they’re defined in the model) has a special status. Django interprets the first Manager defined in a class as the “default” Manager

So to use `objects` by default, put it before `published`:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    objects = models.Manager()
    published = PublishedPostManager()
```

or define it as the default manager in the model `Meta`:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    published = PublishedPostManager()
    objects = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        default_manager_name = 'objects'
```